# How to get the control back in the shell file which has reboot command in it

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to run series of commands in bash shell file. But one of the command requires reboot of the system and I have added reboot command in the shell file. But after the reboot that process is lost. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: [RedHat - 24.5. Scheduling a Job to Run on Next Boot Using a systemd Unit File](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/s1-one-time_script_on_next_boot_using_systemd_unit_file) How you do it will depend on your init system, e.g. `systemd` or `init scripts`.

Comment: You can't directly resume in the script — the system has been rebooted and the script will not be rerun automatically.  You'll have to go through shenanigans to get a script to run during the boot process.

Answer (score 1):

In the system the only thing that is really persistent is a file. That's pretty much what you should use.
Try making the part of the script that needs to be executed after reboot in to `/etc/rc.local` from within the script.

[Reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145294/how-to-continue-a-script-after-it-reboots-the-machine)

Comment: I think most Linux distros use Systemd nowadays, not the SystemV way of doing things.